# Heroku private apps on private space

Tags: heroku

I have few web dynos running on a private space. Some of the web services are public facing and some are internal. How can I configure the private web apps to communicate with each other through Heroku space private network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internal communication in the space can use Dyno DNS Discovery, you need to enable the feature in order to be able to use it - more details at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-dns-registry